# SQL ORDER BY performance

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with more than 1 million records. The problem is that the query takes too much times, like 5 minutes. The "ORDER BY" is my problem, but i need the expression in the query order by to get most popular videos. And because of the expression i can't create an index on it.

How can i resolve this problem?
Thx.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
`v`.`id`,`v`.`url`, `v`.`title`, `v`.`hits`, `v`.`created`, ROUND((r.likes*100)/(r.likes+r.dislikes),0) AS `vote` 
FROM 
`videos` AS `v` 
INNER JOIN 
`votes` AS `r` ON v.id = r.id_video 
ORDER BY 
(v.hits+((r.likes-r.dislikes)*(r.likes-r.dislikes))/2*v.hits)/DATEDIFF(NOW(),v.created) DESC
```

Comment: Why can't you create an index?

Comment: I kinda suspect, that problem isn't in `ORDER BY`. More likely that the `DISTINCT` is the cause. Why is it there ?

Comment: @tereško - Both will have a cost, both involve sorting the data.  The distinct is only on one table, the sort is a composite calculation from both tables.  The order by clause will be the most expensive.  And as the result of the calculation has no relation to an possible index, you are sorting a million rows of randomly ordered data.  Without caching the result of this calculation, it's going to be expensive.

Comment: Why do you have `DISTINCT` there ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the most popular have to be calculated everytime? I doubt if the answer is yes. Some operations will take a long time to run no matter how efficient your query is.

Also bear in mind you have 1 million now, you might have 10 million in the next few months. So the query might work now but not in a month, the solution needs to be **scalable**.

I would make a job to run every couple of hours to calculate and store this information on a different table. This *might not be the answer you are looking for* but I just had to say it.

Comment: +1 : ordering a million results by a calculation that essentially returns a random value (position before sort has zero relation to position after sort) is always going to be expensive.  Best bet is to use some batch process, trigger, or other method, to pre-calculate this value.  You can then have an index on the calculated value.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past is to create a voting system based on Integers. 
Nothing will outperform integers.

The voting system table has 2 Columns:

ProductID

VoteCount (INT)

The votecount stores all the votes that are submitted.

Like = +1

Unlike = -1

Create an Index in the vote table based on ID.

Comment: In this case the calculation depends on many more factors, including relative date.  Your suggestion is essentially "sort it by something simpler" and I don't see that as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to alternatives to improve this:
1) create a new column with the needed value pre-calculated
1) create a second table that holds the videos primary key and the result of the calculation.

This could be a calculated column (in the firts case) or modify your app or add triggers that allow you to keep it in sync (you'd need to manually load it the firs time, and later let your program keep it updated)

If you use the second option your key could be composed of the finalRating plus the primary key of the videos table. This way your searches would be hugely improved.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try moving you arithmetic of the order by into your select, and then order by the virtual column such as:

```
SELECT (col1+col2) AS a
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY a
```

Arithmetic on sort is expensive.

Comment: `Arithmetic on sort is expensive.` True.  But it's identically expensive as your suggested alternative.  The arithmetic is still needed on every record, yielding  randomly ordered set that then needs sorting.  This is an algebraic manipulation that make no difference to the query cost.

Comment: The DB optimizer will know how to rewrite SELECT clause to make it as fast as possible. But as I remember, DB optimizer does not do that for ORDER BY clause. But Yes, you are right arithmetic in any situation is bad on a DB. this probably should be done with code as a post process. Implementing comparable.

Comment: Test it out and see.  `SELECT fn() AS a, * FROM table ORDER BY a` will not perform better than `SELECT * FOM table ORDER BY fn()`